# Show error in function if some other function has not run before it

Tags: c++, arduino

I have two functions in C library that I am making.
One is a setup function, other is a function that does some operations. I want the second operations function to print an error if the setup function has not run before it.
What would be the best way to do this?

Here is what I have in my mind, but I am not sure if that is how it is done.

The setup function:

```
void setup_function()
{
    #ifndef FUNCTION_SETUP
    #define FUNCTION_SETUP
    a_init();
    b_init();
    c_init();
    #endif
}
```

And the operations function:

```
bool operations()
{
    #ifdef FUNCTION_SETUP
    try
    {
        /* My code */
        return true;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        Serial.println("Error in operations");
        return false;
    }
    #elif Serial.println("Function not setup. Please use setup_function() in void setup()");
    #endif
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Also read the tags' descriptions! As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Is there a different way of doing it in C than C++? I mentioned both because my project contains both. But if that is not possible then C only.

Comment: Those are two different languages, despite their similarities.

Comment: I understand that. I will modify my question.

Comment: You could let the `n_init()` functions change a global variable, that `operations()` checks. If the global variable hasn't changed from some default value (0) then the inits were not run.

Comment: The normal way to do this is through documentation, not through software. "Before this function is executed, you must execute function x()".  This is a super common scenario, since pretty much every single C module has some manner of init function. Other than that, you _could_ use some status variable local to the library but that shouldn't be necessary. You can assume that the user of your lib has RTFM you provided in form of function use comments in the header file.

Comment: this looks like an X->Y problem. what do you want to achieve with guards inside functions? it doesn't determine if the setup function was executed, only whether it seen by the compiler

Comment: @Lundin I understand that it is usually mentioned in documentation, and I have done that. But I want it to show an error in case the user doesn't follow the documentation anyway. I see that the recommended way is to use a global bool flag, and that makes sense.

Comment: @Neil assert looks like something I could benefit from. I will try that as well.

Comment: We normally don't use exception handling nor `assert` in embedded systems programming. You'll need a custom error handler suitable for the specific hardware (to print on UART, or a LCD or whatever).

Comment: Sequence verification you're expecting is a typical task for Unit Tests. For instance GTest has dedicated `InSequence` type which assures that `EXPECT_CALL`s are checked requiring the defined order. VectorVAST also allows to create SequenceTests for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#ifndef only checks whether this function was defined somewhere for the compiler and won't affect runtime.

best way to do this is through use of a global variable that changes value once the setup function is executed. if you're defining these functions in classes you could use static data member and setup function

Answer (score 1):

C has a pre-processing command `#error` that can be used to trigger a stop to the compiling. However, the compilation unit is processed in order, *not* ran. Some programmes need to just run to see, (which is related to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).)

The idiomatic way to to runtime checks is with [assert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert), as in this `C99` example. (You would `#include <cassert>` in `C++`.)

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

static bool is_setup; // Can be optimized away with -D NDEBUG.

static void setup_function(void) {
    assert(!is_setup && (is_setup = true));
}

static bool operations(void) {
    assert(is_setup);
    return true;
}

int main(void) {
    //setup_function(); // Triggers `assert` if omitted.
    operations();
    return 0;
}
```

However, `C++` has techniques that encourage [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization); when possible, one should generally use this to set up an object on acquisition and manage the object throughout it's lifetime.